# Reading 1 line from a TXT file online using python

Tags: python, web

i've tried to implement an auto update check into my Python programm.
I want to achieve this by reading the content of a TXT file i hosted on my website (containing just "1.0" ) and checking it with a local variable.

So far i actually got everything working fine. however when i run the script, this is what it reads from the TXT file online

```
b'1.0'
```

This is the code i try to achieve this with

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
CurrentGameVersion = "1.0"
def updateGame():
 with urllib.request.urlopen('http://myWebsite.de/version.txt') as response:
    version = response.read()
if version != CurrentGameVersion:
    print ("Update pls")
    print (version)
    print (CurrentGameVersion)
else:
    print ("Up to Date!")
```

As i said, 
    print (version) 
prints out    b'1.0'
while
print (CurrentGameVersion)
obviously prints out 1.0

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response.read()` call is returning a bytes object, the 'b' at the start of the value indicates that. You should call string.decode() to decode this value. Try this line instead:

```
    version = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```